# What is the pressure point where deviations from ideal gas law occur?

Tags: gas-laws

I read a lot on deviations from ideal gas law due to low temperature and high pressure and I understand it, but I am curious to what point (the value) does a pressure is considered HIGH pressure?

Comment: Let's just say that high pressure means $P \to ∞$ .

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the gas. If the molecules have strong interactions with each other you can see measurable deviations at pressures around 5 atm. But if you have a "more ideal" gas you may have to pressurize it to much higher pressures. There is no set value.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the reduced pressure (pressure divided by critical pressure) and reduced temperature (absolute temperature divided by critical temperature), and then see a plot of compressibility factor z as a function of reduced pressure and reduced temperature (in every thermodynamics text book).  If z differs from 1.0 by more than about 10 %, the ideal gas law will not give very accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

When the non ideal gas reaches Boyle temperature it acts like a ideal over a range of pressures. It is at this temperature that the attractive forces and the repulsive forces acting on the gas particles balance out.